# ​[Tap] to see the difference

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation, clean-up

[tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap) says in the wiki and usage guidance that it refers to two very different things: a unit testing protocol and the mobile idea of clicking. That overload is absurd.

Unfortunately, there appear to be no tags that easily correspond to either tapping or TAP. Should there be? The protocol seems reasonable enough as the subject of a tag, but it's not that large a proportion of the tag at present, which is itself only 380 questions weak. Perhaps we can retag it as [test-anything-protocol]. I'm not entirely sure tapping even needs a tag separate from [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click), but that's as may be.

Comment: I'm all for `[test-anything-protocol]` and it's not that long of a tag name. I would keep `[tap]`, because it's sufficiently different from `[click]`.

Comment: Removing the word "protocol" from its description may also mean it doesn't get used for questions about [this TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telelocator_Alphanumeric_Protocol) (which isn't nice to work with at all...) and has been used for this [at least once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815956/anyone-have-some-tap-or-snpp-examples)

Answer (score 24):

[test-anything-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-anything-protocol) isn't that long.  I'd say go for it.

There are issues with [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap) vs [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) controls that are sufficiently nasty that I could see someone having expertise on the area, or wanting an easy way to search for it.  Now, [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) and [touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch) together basically mean [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap), but that kind of cross-tag meaning is frowned upon.

[tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap) might end up being a really small tag.  But I don't think it is harmful.

A link in its description saying "you might mean [test-anything-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-anything-protocol)" might reduce mistagged things, if that is more common than the actual tap action tagging.