# "tap" tag is ambiguous (mobile phone tap vs. Test Anything Protocol)

Tags: discussion, tags

Most of the `tap` questions are about tapping a mobile phone, not about the [Test Anything Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol), a line/YAML-oriented format for expressing results of unit tests commonly used in Perl projects.

The tag info mentions both meanings:

> The Test Anything Protocol (TAP) is a protocol to allow communication
>   between unit tests and a test harness. On mobile phones, to tap means
>   "to click".

I think we should add a new tag specifically for the Test Anything Protocol (since the volume is low compared to the other meaning of tap) and change the description of `tap` to specifically exclude TAP and suggest the new tag.

This has been mentioned once before:

[​[Tap] to see the difference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309060/tap-to-see-the-difference)

Answer (score -3):

This is what I think should happen and why:

- [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap) → [tap-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap-event):

  - [1,995 questions contain the exact phrase "tap event"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tap+event%22)
  - [68 of 444 questions tagged [tap] contain the exact phrase "tap event"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tap+event%22+%5Btap%5D)
  - [252 of 444 questions tagged [tap] contain the word "event"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=event+%5Btap%5D)
  - [88 tags contain some form of the word "event" in their name](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/734607/912913/)
- [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap) → disambiguated to mean only "Test Anything Protocol":

  - [test-anything-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-anything-protocol) is too long of a tag name
  - There is no parent project or category that would make any sense in any kind of hyphenation that people would actually use
  - People are actually using [tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap) for this purpose already, so it's working
  - I'm sure there are other reasons I just can't think of right now

I'm not overly attached to this solution for "Test Anything Protocol", but my main reasoning is that if you change the tag to something harder to find (like [test-anything-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-anything-protocol)), people aren't going to use it, and if they don't use it, it isn't a useful tag.

Comment: What's wrong with a 22-character unambiguous tag name?

Comment: @Nathan If no one uses it it isn't a very useful tag. We can disambiguate tap to tap-event much easier and people will actually use that, as evidenced by the research linked in my answer. Why replace a tag that people use with one that they won't? It can be as unambiguous as you want, but everywhere I look for Test Anything Protocol, it is referred to as "TAP" directly thereafter.

Comment: I am a very firm believer in maximal disambiguation whenever practical — just disambiguating *one* side of a confusion isn't necessarily good enough. And for something derp-friendly like "tap" (which has, remember, already suffered being seriously outnumbered in its proper use) I think it's worth the extra trouble to make it extra clear.

Comment: By the way, I'd forgotten until just now that I'd already posted a disambiguation request making the same suggestion… at least I'm consistent across years.

Comment: @Nathan I disagree for the reasons I've stated, but as I said I'm not overly attached to the outcome.

Comment: Before consensus has been reached no action should be taken.

Comment: Neither of these proposals have met the threshold (indicating community consensus) for action, @Gregory, and [tag removals must be documented and discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta). Keep in mind that even once a tag removal request reaches community consensus, [there's a large backlog on these requests, and it may take a while for it to be actioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356820/why-do-some-burninate-request-with-over-20-votes-not-get-featured/356821#356821).